# unable to play video in iOS 4

Tags: ios, ios4, media-player

I have written code to play video in iPhone OS 3.1.3 and video is playing fine.

but when i am trying to play video with the same code then video is not playing in iOS 4.

I know that Media player framework is changed for iOS 4. Is there any way i can play the video on different OS without preparing separate binary??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First check if you are on OS 3.2 or above. If yes, create a movie player the new way:

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"UISplitViewController") != nil) {
  MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:yourURL];
  [[mp moviePlayer] prepareToPlay];
  [[mp moviePlayer] setShouldAutoplay:YES];
  [[mp moviePlayer] setControlStyle:2];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoPlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
  [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];
} else {
  moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:yourURL];
  [self playMovieTheOldWay:moviePlayer];
}
```

You can close the new movie player like this:

```
-(void)videoPlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{       
  [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. with which sdk i will have to compile the application in this case??

Comment: The "new media player" came with 3.2 so you need 3.2 or above to compile this. You cannot use the new media player with an old sdk.

Comment: If i am compiling the application against the SDK 3.2 and later then will this application run on 3.1.3 or not??

Comment: If you set the deployment target to 3.1, it will work, even if linked and built with 4.0 (only new methods won't work - like movieplayerviewcontroller, which doesn't exists prior to 3.2).

Comment: Thanks i am able to run application with above implementation on OS 3.1.3 and OS 4.0.Really appreciate your help.