# html5 video playing in iPad 3.2 but not in 4.1

Tags: ipad, html, video, ios4

I have created a web safe video by Saving for web in quicktime, now in the web page that video is playing when I select Version 3.2 for the SDK but it does not work when I select 4.0 or 4.1.
Is there any thing changed about the video?

Comment: possible duplicate of [unable to play video in iOS 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341782/unable-to-play-video-in-ios-4)